# alarm clock with a buzzer python

Tags: python-3.x, time

I'm trying to make an alarm clock with a buzzer. The buzzer will go off when the time changes every hour and also when 15 minutes pass.
For example:

Current time : 3:00pm; the buzzer goes off three times since it's 3 o'clock and at 
3:15 - buzzes again (15 minutes passed).

4:00 - the buzzer buzzes four times
4:15 - the buzzer buzzes again

I'm working with python. 
Any help?

Answer (score -3):

If you haven't done:

```
import time
```

your code wont be able to access the current time, but to really help you with this we would need to see how far you have got with your code.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet .. im trying to search for help on how to do it. Thank you though. Does import datetime work ?